# Adding a picture from a resource to a picture box

Tags: c#

I got this issue with displaying a image that i allready have added as a resource. I am guessing i am missing something vital but i cant find what it is. I am hoping that someone has a better idea of what i am doing wrong atm.

I have added an .bmp image into the solutiontree and changed the build action properties of that image to Embedded resource but i cant figure out how to call that image from the pipe?

as the user clicks a button the image should be sent to the imagebox, the code i have written so far looks like this:

this is ofs only the button_click code:

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show image in the picturebox of selected cake   

        Image image = Image.FromFile(fruitcake.jpg);
        pictbox.Image = image;
        pictbox.Height = 163;
        pictbox.Width = 223;
        choice = 1;
        lblCookiesPerGram.Text = string.Empty;           
    }
```

Anyone has an idea of what i am doing wrong or can i do this in another war? mind thou its 4 buttons the user clicks and there is a image for each one ;)

//Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve an image from a resource, you can do something like:

```
using (Stream imgStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream(
    "MyNamespace.resources.fruitcake.jpg"))
{
    var image = new Bitmap(imgStream);
    pictBox.Image = image;
    pictBox.Height = image.Height;
    pictBox.Width = image.Width;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you go to your Solution - Properties window and select the Resources tab and add the image through this manager, then the images can be directly referenced like this:

```
Image image = Properties.Resources.fruitcake;
```

Comment: This will only work if the OP has actually added the image to the actual resx file for the project, and not just put it into the Resources directory.